# Wikidata SPARQL query timeout: country flags sorted by population

Tags: sparql, wikidata

With the following SPARQL query I’m trying to list countries with their national flags in descending order of population.
I cannot run it without it reaching a timeout limit. It runs in ~2s when the indicated line is commented out (but this returns the cartesian product of all countries and all national flags, not just the associated pairs).

```
SELECT ?country ?countryLabel ?flag ?population

WHERE {
    ?country wdt:P31 wd:Q6256;
             wdt:P1082 ?population.

    ?flag wdt:P31 wd:Q186516.
    ?flag wdt:P1001 ?country. # runs without this line
  
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}

ORDER BY DESC(?population)
LIMIT 100
```

[Try it here](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fcountry%20%3FcountryLabel%20%3Fflag%20%3Fpopulation%0A%0AWHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ6256%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP1082%20%3Fpopulation.%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fflag%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ186516%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP1001%20%3Fcountry.%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22.%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0AORDER%20BY%20DESC%28%3Fpopulation%29%0ALIMIT%20100)

Does anyone know why this query is to complex to compute, and how to get it to run? Thanks!

Comment: the problem is often the label `SERVICE` - the same holds for your query, try it without

Comment: alternatively, use standard RDF way: `SELECT ?country ?countryLabel ?flag ?population

WHERE {
    ?country wdt:P31 wd:Q6256;
             wdt:P1082 ?population.

    ?flag wdt:P31 wd:Q186516;
          wdt:P1001 ?country.
    ?country rdfs:label ?countryLabel.
    FILTER ( lang(?countryLabel) = "en" )
  
   
}

ORDER BY DESC(?population)
LIMIT 100`

Comment: @UninformedUser Thanks. That’s strange. Any idea why `SERVICE` causes a problem here, or why it often does?

Comment: not sure, I guess it's basically a query optimizer thing, it's a non-standard SPARQL magic feature, so nice to have but sometimes you have to workaround it